# Предупреждение: "deprecated or antiquated header"

Tags: c++

Я начал изучать язык C++, скачал программу Dev-C++ для компилирования и книгу «Освой C++ за 21 день». В книге написан код типа моей первой программы, я его переписал, вот кстати он:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Дальше компилирую, но выдается ошибка:

> 32:2 F:\Dev-Cpp\include\c++\3.4.2\backward\backward_warning.h #warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated header. Please consider using one of the 32 headers found in section 17.4.1.2 of the C++ standard. Examples include substituting the  header for the  header for C++ includes, or  instead of the deprecated header . To disable this warning use -Wno-deprecated.

Нажимаю выполнить, но мне в ответ: «проект не откомпилирован».

Где источник ошибки? Может, что-то не так с кодом?

Comment: мой Вам совет, купите книгу Герберт Шилдт - с++. руководство для начинающих
Она достаточно простая. Пользы будет намного больше чем от Вашей и не будет возникать таких вопросов

Comment: Изучите среду разработки, ее особенности; каждая со своими прибамбасами, а прога написана правильно. Удачи. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Напишите:

```
#include <iostream>
```

и далее

```
using namespace std;
```

Видимо, книга у Вас достаточно старая (и, вообще, "...за 21 день" меня всегда пугают)

Код должен принять, например, такой вид:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

P.S. Если есть вопросы "почему" - спрашивайте, ответим.

Comment: ха, спс, я написал код так, все правильно, но почему то у меня прога не запускается, окно быстро открывается и сразу же закрывается, я ничего не успеваю сделать, и от имени администратора запускал, она моргнет и все, помогите плизз)

Comment: Это консольное приложение. Или выставьте в свойствах приложения, чтобы окно не закрывалось при завершении или запускайте из командной строки

Comment: а поподробней можно? а то я чет не совсем понял, че в свойствах делать и как из конс строки запускать??

Answer (score 4):

Мой совет -- смените книжку. По стандарту надо писать

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, word!" << std::endl;
}
```

А книжка старая у вас очень.

ЗЫ в качестве прикола [image: картинка]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообщето всё было правильно и в первый раз, просто у тебя консолька моментально выключается. нужно добавить библиотеку 
    #include<conio.h>
И в конце, перед ретюрном написать
    _getch();
    return 0;

Comment: conio.h? Закопайте стюардессу!