# Как должен выглядеть код для современного компилятора?

Tags: c++

> Сделано вопросом из комментария в [теме](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/20147/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-deprecated-or-antiquated-header) (@ХэшКод).

И вообще, эта книга не старая, она 2007 года, просто в ней автор решил код писать по-старому, чтобы читатели со старыми компиляторами могли работать, но у меня по-старому коду не получается, объясните плизз, вот, например, этот код:

```
#include <iostream.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << x + y << * * << x * y;
    cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Это по-старому, объясните, как надо плизз.

Разобрался с командной строкой, ну, как запускать, а подскажите еще, как запускать обычно, но чтоб не закрывалась??

Answer (score 2):

Что б не закрывалась командная строка после выполнения? Обычно делали вот так:

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream.h>

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    cout << "\n";
    cout << x + y << * * << x * y;
    cout << "\n";
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вместо getch(); так же возможно system("pause")

Comment: по-моему надо писать _getch(); По крайней мере если в Visual Studio работаете

Comment: getch() или _getch() - это уже зависит от версии Visual Studio.. Первая - для старых версий, вторая - для новых.

Answer (score 2):

> Разобрался с командной строкой, ну, как запускать, а подскажите еще, как запускать обычно, но чтоб не закрывалась??

Вы лукавите,сеньор!Если Вы разобрались с коммандной строкой(консоль?),то для винды надо добавлять

> getch();

в Unix,а пример написан для него ,гетч не нужен,окошко не закрывается,попробуйте поставить себе хоть бубунту на виртуальной машине,дело пойдет быстрее и с пользой,имхо.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что дело, наверное, идёт про стандарты кодирования С++

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    //cout << x + y << * * << x * y; //Эти две звёздочки вообще обрадовали)
    std::cout << x + y << "Semo text" << x * y;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <clocale>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int x = 5;
    int y = 7;
    cout<<endl; \\ замисть cout << "\n";
    cout << x + y << * * << x * y;
    cout<<endl; \\ замисть cout << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ответ не понятно от кого и никак не связанный с вопросом!

Answer (score 0):

Кто вам сказал что символ 'n' не удовлетворяет стандартам? endl кроме перевода строки  осуществляет очистку буфера потока, а это не всегда нужно.

Чтобы ваша программа была "по стандарту" измените заголовки:

## include <iostream>

using namespace std;